# ReporteRs Character NAs Blank

Tags: r, reporters

I would like to make a FlexTable that makes NA values appear as NA. When the column is of class numeric, I am able to do this. When the column is of class character, the cell appears empty. Is there a way to get my NA values to appear when they are part of a column of class character? I am aware that I could simply replace them with "NA", but I would strongly prefer not to do this.

```
library(ReporteRs)

y <- data.frame(var.1 = as.character(letters[1:5]), 
                var.2 = as.numeric(1:5), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y[3, 1] <- NA
y[4, 2] <- NA

FlexTable(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add quotes around NA values.

```
library(ReporteRs)

y <- data.frame(var.1 = as.character(letters[1:5]), 
                var.2 = as.numeric(1:5), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y[3, 1] <- "NA"
y[4, 2] <- "NA"

FlexTable(y)
```

Comment: I would like to have a value in a character column in my data that appears when using FlexTable() and is a true NA, i.e. is.na() == TRUE. Is this possible?

Comment: No, there is no function for formatting content. Have a try with package flextable and function display (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/format.html#display-function)